# Symfony won't read database connection parameters from parameters.yml

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a copy of an existing symfony2 website, the original version is working fine, the copy don't beacause of database conneciont problems : I updated parameters.yml so the copy can connect to its own database. The user (db_copy) and password are different from original site's database (user : db_original)

The copy is trying to connecte to the original db. In the logs I have this :

```
 PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_original'@'localhost'
```

As you can see the copy is using original's parameters ! I thought the copy is not reading it's own parameters.yml file, so I renamed id : the copy says it can't find "parameters.yml" : so it seems to read the right file !

I disabled APC cache from symfony config (commented all instructions in config_dev.yml > doctrine : orm :), I also run this :

```
php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query
php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

I also tried to force db parametres in this file :

```
/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php
```

The problem remains : the copy still want to connect to db_original ! It sounds crazy, the updates in PDOMySql/Driver.php have no effects at all ! It seems symfony is not using that file at all ! PLEASE HELP :(

Comment: Did you perform a **php app/console cache:clear** after copying your original project ?

Comment: yes ! I tried cache:clear, cache:warmup, rm -rf app/cache/ ... the problem remains !

Comment: Did you try to restart your HTTP server ?

Comment: I don't have the permission to do it ! Should I ask the host manager to do it ?

Comment: On the dev or prod frontal controller? Check config.yml, config_prod.yml & config_dev.yml

Comment: i'm using prod controller. When I run "php app/console doctrine:ensure-production-settings" it says "Environment is correctly configured for production." Now the site is working fine, I don't know even how ! All I did is "app/console cache:clear" then "php app/console doctrine:ensure-production-settings", then the site is running !!